# Withdraw ether from other miner

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, python

I'm working with blockchain ethereum private network with several miners. I already successfully send and stamp a transaction from (example) one minerA to minerB using web3 library in python language. I want to ask, is it possible to make a withdraw function (without SC) that minerB will send back ether to minerA? But it happened as a request from minerA (minerB is not directly make a transaction to send ether to minerA). So what i want to make is minerA trigger minerB to send a transaction but still using blockchain architecture. Please tell me if it's possible or not, and correct me if my understanding about the transaction is wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I'm understanding what you want to do entirely, so I'm going to try to rephrase your question, and please correct me if I got something wrong:
Using a blockchain framework, but no smart contracts ("without SC"), can I get an account to send a transaction whenever it receives a transaction?

If that is the case, I suspect the answer is that it depends on what you're willing to automate. You could theoretically run a script that uses something like `web3.py` to monitor the blockchain, and then when some specific condition is met, sends a transaction from your miner B to miner A. You would need to make a listener that would look over each new block looking for the 'request' from miner A, and then if that condition is met, have it send the transaction you'd like to miner A from miner B.

Comment: thank you for your reply and sorry if my question is hard to understand. i think it's not possible, maybe i will just use a smart contract then.